# Посещение сайта не засчитывается для получения знака "Фанатик"

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Вот решил заработать: **Фанатик** - *Посещать сайт ежедневно в течение 100 дней подряд. (Учет дней по UTC.)*
[image: Пропущенный день]

Как можно заметить из картинки один день у меня выпал. Но в этот день я посещал SO 100%. Я начал экспериментировать с посещениями на `stackoverflow.com`, `meta.stackoverflow.com`, `meta.ru.stackoverflow.com`, `ru.stackoverflow.com` и вот нашел баг. **Посещение главной страницы сайта не засчитывается как посещение сайта. Вот скрины в доказательство.**

Скрин посещения как руского SO, так и основного:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и собственно скрин того, что посещение не засчиталось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу исправить данный баг и засчитать мне на акк [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632019/eugen-konkov?tab=profile) знак "Фанатик", т.к. там я посетил 100 дней подряд.

Comment: Стоит ли перевести этот пост на английский?

Comment: Вот так. А я даже не знаю, куда надо кликать, чтобы увидеть такой календарик...

Comment: кстати, бага возможна, фанатика на enso получил почти просто потому, что по рабочим/хобби вопросам заходил, на ruso периодически то ли дни пропадают, то ли черт его знает (уже не интересовался)

Comment: @avp: клацайте на предложение "Visited X days, Y consecutive"

Comment: @strangeqargo я так пологаю страница может как-то из кеша отдаваться. Это ж главная страница и запросов море, поэтому не грех её закешировать. И, соответственно, если страница отдалась из кеша, то посещение не засчитывается, т.к. код, который делает учёт посещений, не выполнился.

Comment: @avp то, что вы за этим не следите, говорит только в пользу вашего психического благополучия. Я вот следил, и когда добыл-таки знак, испытал существенное облегчение. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jeff Atwood пишет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/296059), что так и должно быть:

```
2010-10-03 02:09:19 user accessed site
2010-10-02 06:32:30 login
2010-10-01 01:07:43 user accessed site
```

> We see a login on 10-2 but no access to internal pages (login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access").
>
> Видно, что вы заходили на сайт 2 октября, но не открывали никаких внутренних страниц (страница входа на сайт и несколько других домашних страниц не считаются "посещением" сайта).

Ну и давайте будем честны. Механика получения знака довольно простая и её легко обойти. Но задуман знак всё-таки для поощрения тех, кто принимает активное участие или хотя бы читает какие-то вопросы и ответы.

Кстати, учитывайте, что ваш часовой пояс - GMT+3 (вычислил по скриншотам). Поэтому когда вы заходите на сайт в час ночи 10 числа, засчитывается посещение 9 числа.

Активность в мобильном приложении учитывается.

Comment: Задачу на получение "Фанатика" можно сформулировать продуктивно: каждый день давать хороший ответ или голосовать за хороший ответ/вопрос кого-то другого. Получится 100 маленьких добрых дел :) За такое не стыдно и в фанатики попасть.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky за такое можно даже высылать пачку ромашкового чая для успокоения нервов. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну и если такое дело, что нужно читать вопросы и ответы, то тогда нужно так и писать: **Читать ежедневно вопросы или ответы в течение 100 дней подряд** А то получается 2.5 месяца читал, на 86й день быстро заскочил (не знаю, может торопился куда) и ппц. начинай всё сначала :`-((( Хотя по факту посещение было.

Comment: Может я не увидел интересных вопросов в этот день, вот и не читал их, но сайт посещал же! :-D